# How to place / store a file in memory on linux?

Tags: linux, files, memory

I have read somewhere that one can put a file on a linux system into memory, and loading it will be superfast.

How do I do this? How do I verify the file is loaded from memory?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

On Linux, you probably already have an `tmpfs` filesystem that you can write to at `/dev/shm`.

```
$ >/dev/shm/foo
$ df /dev/shm/foo
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                   224088         0    224088   0% /dev/shm
```

This may use swap, however. For a true ramdisk (that won't swap), you need to use the `ramfs` filesystem.

```
mount ramfs -t ramfs /mountpoint
```

Comment: Will this be then available to apache/php? I am interested in using this for a chat app and plan to save/retrieve recent lines from memory to avoid HDD write/read overhead.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a *ramdisk*. You can simply mount your RAM as follows:

```
mount tmpfs <mountpoint> -t tmpfs -o size=2G
```

This creates a ramdisk of 2 GiB. For more information see `man mount` and search for `tmpfs`.

Comment: This is not truly a ramdisk, `tmpfs` can swap.

Comment: http://www.jamescoyle.net/knowladge/951-the-difference-between-a-tmpfs-and-ramfs-ram-disk